# Python - download video using web scraping

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that downloads a video using the webpage's [url](https://fmovies.wtf/film/adventures-of-rufus-the-fantastic-pet.72o71) as an argument for practice. I basically have two questions.

First:
I am unable to find the iframe source with the following code in order to switch to it in Python. Are there any reasons or things I'm missing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://fmovies.wtf/film/adventures-of-rufus-the-fantastic-pet.72o71'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')

soup.find_all('iframe')
```

Second: 
While looking through the html of the website on Google Chrome I'm also unable to find the source of the video that I would need to use to download the video with. If you could suggest what I'm missing in order to find the video url that would work code that would be a great help:

```
import requests

def download_file(video_url):

    local_filename = 'potatoes.mp4'

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)

    return local_filename

download_file(**THIS IS WHERE THE VIDEO_URL WOULD GO**)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated steering my in the right direction as I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of the page `view-source:https://fmovies.wtf/film/adventures-of-rufus-the-fantastic-pet.72o71` (Copy and paste it in Chrome Address Bar), you'll see that there is no iframe in Source, so it's probably being rendered into DOM by javascript at runtime.

Using `requests` you only get the serve-side-rendered source (the link which I shared above) and since iframe is not being rendered by Server bs4 will not be able to find it!

What should you do? Goto Selenium-based Web Scraping or dig through the Network Panel to see if you could find any API Request that is fetching the URL of the Iframe or any piece of code that is rendering that iframe into DOM.

TLDR; You can't scrape client-side rendered elements using `requests` library.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! In your opinion would it be better to use Selenium or seach through the network Panel?

Comment: @marplaar It completely depends on the website and it's security. If you can get it working through the network panel by finding an exposed API, go for it because then you can directly use the standard method of scraping with Requests and BS4, if not Selenium is your friend.